# Display multiple lines using multiple patterns

Tags: grep

Hope you can shed some light in one of my requirements. Let say I have file with the following entries:

```
ABC 123
XYZ 789
XYZ 456
ABC 234
XYZ 789
ABC 567
XYZ 789
XYZ 678
XYZ 123
```

Basically, I have rows ABC with X numbers of XYZ rows after it. The number of XYZ records in each ABC varies from 1 to many.

I need a shell script that will output the ABC and the corresponding XYZ based on the patterns in the 2nd column.

For example, display the ABC record with pattern 567 and the corresponding XYZ record with pattern 678.

The output should only be:

```
ABC 567
XYZ 678
```

Comment: Do you want to search ABC and 567 (by example) literally ?

Comment: Shouldn't a query for 567 locate all three of the following XYZ lines, not just the middle one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I use `awk` to massage the data into a single line, then `grep` on that output, then `sed` to revert matching entries to the original format.

```sh
awk '{ printf ($1 == "ABC" ? "\n" : " @¶@ ") $0 }' file |grep 567 |sed 's/ @¶@ /\n/g'
```

Code walk:

- I used `@¶@` as a delimiter. Use something that won't have conflicts in your data (otherwise you'll have to deal with escaping it). Also note that your UTF8 support mileage may vary.
- `awk` prints, without trailing line break, two things concatenated:

  - If we're on an ABC line, a line break (`\n`).  Otherwise, the delimiter (`@¶@`).
  - Then the existing line (`$0`)
- `grep` then runs for your query.  This lets you use `-f FILE_OF_PATTERNS` or a collection of `-e PATTERN`s
- `sed` then reverts the delimiters back to the original format

This has the advantage of going line by line.  If you have tens of thousands of XYZs in a single ABC, it'll be a bit slower, but this doesn't keep anything in memory, so this should be pretty scalable.

Here is the output of the above `awk` command (yes, there is a leading blank line, which doesn't matter):

```sh
$ awk '{ printf ($1 == "ABC" ? "\n" : " @¶@ ") $0 }' file

ABC 123 @¶@ XYZ 789 @¶@ XYZ 456
ABC 234 @¶@ XYZ 789
ABC 567 @¶@ XYZ 789 @¶@ XYZ 678 @¶@ XYZ 123
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if it works for you. I hope I understood your requirement right:

```
 awk -v p1='ABC 567' -v p2='XYZ 678' 
       '$0~p1{t=1;print;next}/^ABC/{t=0}$0~p2&&t' file
```

Comment: Hi Kent, I forgot to mention that I have a long list of pattern to run